# How to use AnyClass in Swift Generic class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, generics, swift2

I need to pass a type in my generic base class.

```
class SomeBaseClass<T: AnyClass> {
   // Implementation Goes here
}
```

I get the following error:

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'AnyClass' (aka
>   'AnyObject.Type')

Ideally I would like to use 'T' to be as a specific type rather than AnyClass, but AnyClass is OK as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `AnyObject` if you want the type to be a class.

```
class SomeBaseClass<T: AnyObject> {
    // Implementation Goes here
}

// Legal because UIViewController is a class
let o1 = SomeBaseClass<UIViewController>()

// Illegal (won't compile) because String is a struct
let o2 = SomeBaseClass<String>()
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of specifying `T` needs to be a class, you could instead do:

```
class SomeBaseClass<T> {
    let type: T.Type

    init(type: T.Type) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

If you're planning to be using `T.Type` a lot it may be worth using a `typealias`:

```
class SomeBaseClass<T> {
    typealias Type = T.Type
    let type: Type
    ...
}
```

Some example usage:

```
let base = SomeBaseClass(type: String.self)
```

And advantage of this method is `T.Type` could represent structs and enums, as well as classes.

Comment: This is quite interesting, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Neat. Thanks, that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick:

```
protocol P {}

class C: P {}

class C1<T: P> {}

let c1 = C1<C>()
```

In this case you wrap you class `C` with protocol `P`, then you able to create new generic class `C1` where `T` is your protocol `P`. That's allow you to create instance of `C1` class with generic parameter class `C`.